What remains true after condensation?
As I slowly develop intuition for the condensed formalism, I feel that it’d help greatly if there were a principle or meta-theorem which said that certain kinds of statements that are true in ordinary categories (of sets, groups, rings …) should remain true when stated in the corresponding condensed categories.
Just to give a couple of examples of the sort I have in mind:
(1) Classification of finitely generated abelian groups
(2) Galois theory of fields
Is there a guiding principle that helps transport results in 'pre-condensed' mathematics to the condensed realm without much ado? In general ‘condensation’ should restrict their applicability, but perhaps there is a way to identify or predict those that go through essentially verbatim.

Voted to close because this post is incredibly vague. Do you have an example of a statement that you know in the condensed setting that generalises a classical one? I don't really think it works like that: condensed abelian groups are supposed to behave like topological abelian groups, not like ordinary abelian groups.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn, One of the rationales given for the invention of condensed formalism is that it allows restoration of the truth of certain desirable statements which fail when moved from an ordinary algebraic category (e.g., the abelian category of abelian groups) to its topological counterpart. The question is precisely inspired  by it. Since the scope of condensed mathematics is vast and foundational, it is good to ask if there are parts of algebra that can be relatively effortlessly carried over to the condensed setting. If not, lot of fun translation work to look forward to!
